# How do docker containers or services find each other specifically in a particular network?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a web(frontend and backend) application and a database running as services under the same network. How would the backend service or the container specifically find out the database service(container) and communicate with that?? How would the backend service particularly have the database service's IP (let's say the DNS name or the container name) as the database endpoint in it's application when there is frontend service too in the network???

Comment: By dns name. For example db service has name db.

Comment: Yeah but its just a name. How come the backend will know that the database is named db?? It's like if I have a normal local environment then localhost and port 5432 would be my psql db. That way how is the backend able to know without us defining anything in it?

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do. But you can use name "db" in your stack file as name of your db. You can pass it as env variable or .env file which can be different in different environment.

Comment: Can I see test or example github project?

Comment: I don't have any project I was just considering a scenario. I know for a fact that the containers communicate with each other within a network using their DNS names which are like the container names most of the time. Let me make it a little simple, what if I have mysql and psql services running along with the backend service then how would the backend know which database service it should be using?? Sorry Im a new to Docker. You can take this link as reference where at the end he has changed the localhost to mongodb. https://itnext.io/dockerize-a-node-js-app-connected-to-mongodb-64fdeca94797

Comment: If you are using docker you don't need to install mongo localy. You can add mongo service in compose file as it described in your link in 4. Dockerize Node and MongoDb

Comment: You should learn more about docker https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

Comment: Yeah I would do that I mean dockerize mongo too but still my question is how would the backend know which DB endpoint to connect to? It should be defined in my source code isnt it?

Comment: I have found out that the way the web application connects to the database container or service depends on the DB connection code written in the web application.

Answer (score 0):

The database connection code on the backend can be written by use of environmental variables instead of hardcode them(Example: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD). While creating an Dockerfile for the application we can define ENV variables within it and these can be even overridden during the startup of the container. If one is using docker compose, we can define these database variables either in a .env file which can be used in the docker-compose.yml or we can directly define the environmental variables inside the docker-compose.yml. I suggest one to have a .env file because that usually acts a bridge between our source code and docker-compose file and by changing the variables there we can make sure our container runs fine without looking at the compose file or source code. Therefore, the docker container like a backend container finds a database container.